# SQL - find prior string value

Tags: sql

I have a DB which 'tracks' the customer shopping journey.  What I want to do is recall the previous value if their final destination or 'shop' is a particular value.

For example say the shops are named like this:

```
Shop 1
Shop 2
Shop 3
Shop 4
```

If my select query returns Shop 4 (for any customer) then I want the extra column to show the previous shop they last shopped at.  There is no natural order to my data so I can't literally state that Shop 4 = Shop 3 it just needs to return whatever shop they *last* shopped at if the last one is Shop 4 (there previous shop could be any 'shop').

This is what I have so far but it's probably way off the mark.  I have a date column in my table but don't know how to use it in this way.

```
Select ...
case
when TableShop.ShopName LIKE 'Shop4' then
cast(TableShop.ShopName -1 AS nvarchar(50))
end
From ...
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you want us to guess you data model also  ?

Comment: Hi both,  thanks for your replies.  Excuse my ignorance but I don't know what you mean by 'what database' and 'model'?
I'm using SQL Server 2008 if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you have *some* column that specifies the ordering of the visits -- say a `visitDatetime` column.

Then, you can use the ANSI standard `LAG()` function:

```
select s.*,
       (case when s.shopName = 'Shop4'
             then lag(s.shopName) over (partition by customerId order by visitDateTime)
        end) as prev_ShopName
from tableshop s;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon - I've just found out that LAG() doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008.  Thank you - sorry for not stating this in my original post.

Comment: @cheese_and_pickle . . . You should tag your question with the database you are using.